# Added a real life image to an illustration. How do i make it match?/Look better?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

[image: Ilustrated dog with realistic lei]

I've added the lei to the dog and it just seems wrong because the dog is cartoony and the lei is realistic, it contrasts too much. how do i fix this?

Comment: errr.. draw the lei.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- draw it
- trace it in a vector programme such as Inkscape or Illustrator
- apply Photoshop artistic filters to "sketchify" it

Answer (score 0):

I selected the lei, went to

```
Filter > Filter Gallery > Cutout
```

And played around with the values until I got something that looks half-way decent (I ended up with 5 levels, 3 edge simplicity, 2 edge fidelity).

[image]